# Получение id билда (REST API)

Tags: jenkins

Прикладная задача, отправив задание в jenkins потом мониторить статус выполнения задания. Для решения этой задачи мне нужен идентификатор сборки, его можно получить так
http://rootURL/job/run_update/api/xml?xpath=//lastBuild/number/text()
но, его я могу получить только когда jenkins запустил задание, но он негодяй начинает выполнение с рандомной задержкой, от 1 до 4 секунд, если запросить lastBuild до того как запустилось задание, вернется предыдущий id. Еще заметил такую странность, когда я посылаю get запрос buildWithParameters ... в хедере в лакейшен мне возвращается https://rootURL/queue/item/858 только что это за число 858 не понятно, по этому url 404. Чего делать, как быть?

Comment: А почему не начать мониторить с задержкой секунд в 5-10, чтобы дженкинс гарантировано запустил задание?

Comment: не подходит этот вариант для случаев если я планирую несколько заданий подряд, ну или мне придется планировать с такой большой задержкой

Comment: Потому и не пытался как ответ оформить,  что не универсальный вариант :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить эту проблему с помощью скрипта.

Когда задание запускается удаленно, возвращаемые заголовки имеют URL-адрес номера в очереди заданий (/queue/item/858). Используя это можно сделать ещё несколько запросов API, чтобы получить статус.

шаги:

- Запустить сборку через API
- словить в ответе заголовок 'Location'
- добавть к нему '/api/json', например https://rootURL/jenkins/queue/item/858/api/json
- опрашивать его, пока через какое-то время в ответе не появится секция "executable" - там будет номер задания после его запуска и его url.

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507262/retrieve-id-of-remotely-triggered-jenkins-job), например есть имплементация скрипта на Python.

Comment: так нет такой страницы https://rootURL/queue/item/858

Comment: поправил ответ.  Не забывайте, что из очереди объекты удаляются сборщиком мусора через несклоько минут после того, как попали на выполнение.